# How to highlight filler words (Um, uh, ah) in transcript?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-speech

Is there a configuration in google cloud speech that allows me to see the filler words in the returned JSON transcript? Currently, it seems like the transcript returned by google cloud speech automatically filters out such words (uh, um, ah, like, etc..).

I've attempted to use the 'phrases' parameter in my audio recognize call, which puts emphasis on detecting specific phrases in the audio.

```
wordsToDetect = ["um", "like", "so", "honestly", "basically", "actually", "uh"]

audio = speech.audio output_filepath,
                     encoding: :flac,
                     language: "en-US"

results = audio.recognize phrases: wordsToDetect
```

Is it the case that Google Cloud Speech simply automatically filters out filler words like "um" and "uhhh"?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the Speech recognition APIs are not able to detect the filler sounds like Ahs,Ums, Uhs etc.In order to detect those sounds the algorithm has to be trained to detect those particular sounds.

Comment: Can you tell some good approch to detect filler sounds as mentioned in the questions?